# how to export the sublayers of a saved VRP layer to shapefile with arcpy

Tags: arcpy, network-analyst

I have a bunch of saved layers of the result of VRP, I want to merge the route layers into one file, but apparently I first need to save them as shapefiles. 
When I run this code for one of them, I get this error:

```
import arcpy
import os
import sys
from arcpy import env
directory = r'C:\\test'
shp_out = os.path.join(directory, 'output.shp')
layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers('results_MakeVRP.lyr',"Routes")[0]
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(layers, shp_out)
```

Error:

```
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\utils.py", line 182, in fn_
return fn(*args, **kw)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\mapping.py", line 1517, in ListLayers
result = mixins.MapDocumentMixin(map_document_or_layer).listLayers(wildcard, data_frame)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\arcobjects\mixins.py", line 846, in listLayers
layers = self.layers
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\arcobjects\mixins.py", line 698, in layers
for frame in reversed(self.dataFrames):
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\arcobjects\mixins.py", line 710, in dataFrames
return map(convertArcObjectToPythonObject, self.pageLayout.dataFrames)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\arcobjects\mixins.py", line 694, in pageLayout
return convertArcObjectToPythonObject(self._mxd._arc_object.pageLayout)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_arc_object'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `ListLayers` to get `Layer` objects from a .lyr file. You need to create a [`Layer`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/layer-class.htm) object from the .lyr file first.

You should use this code:

```
vrp_lyr_obj = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"C:\GIS\Temp\ArcGISHomeFolder\VRP.lyr")
vrp_routes_lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(vrp_lyr_obj, 'Routes')[0]
vrp_routes_lyr
#<map layer u'Routes'>

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(vrp_routes_lyr, r'C:\GIS\Temp\ArcGISHomeFolder\scratch.gdb\out_vrp_routes')
<Result 'C:\\GIS\\Temp\\ArcGISHomeFolder\\scratch.gdb\\out_vrp_routes'>
```